# What have to be done to transform a program into a robust OpenMP-aware version?

Tags: c++, c, openmp

The program in question operates on a single input data file and single output data file: it takes a data unit from input, computes several statistical characteristics of the data, puts the characteristics into output.

It was discovered that the program is CPU-bound: CPU usage is 99% al the time, computations take more time than reading and writing. It was decided to convert the program into parallell-processing version by using OpenMP, since the hardware has 32 CPUs available. However, it is clear that it could lead to writing race conditions, since multiple parallell threads may wish to write into single output.

What are necessary steps to prepare such kind of programs to be OpenMP-aware and OpenMp-safe? Could it be easily achived only by OpenMP pragmas without code changes or there must be some locking mechanisms implemented before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficulty to parallelise your code really depends on the complexity of the routine(s) that use up most time.

The first thing you should do before you to any parallel computing is to profile your code and to identify which function exactly causes most of the CPU time.

Once you have that you need to ask yourself the questions:

- Does it have data dependencies?
- If yes, can I get rid of them by making copies of certain affordable data structures?
- If not are they read/write or read only?
- If they are read/write, how often are they accessed - choose the right locking mechanism depending on that.
- Do I have read/write global variables? If yes - can they be made thread-local? If not - get rid of them.
- Once you have all that sorted decide what the best way is to split your input onto threads (see OpenMP scheduling for details)
- Start writing pragmas, rearranging code, making functions thread-safe/reentrant.
- Last bust not least: Debug, Debug, Debug. Try to design small examples of input/output that are reproducible in a multithreaded application.

To answer your last question: `stdio` library calls are all thread safe. They use internal locking.

One hint for your first `#pragma omp parallel`: by default all variables are shared, define them as unavailable and specify sharing/private for each variable individually. This is otherwise a common pitfall for bugs:

```
#pragma omp parallel default(none)
```

Comment: Consider that the program has only three functions: `read`, `compute` and `write`. Let's consider that the program was already profiled and it was found that `compute` takes the 99% CPU time. If `compute` operates on local variables only, then the problem resides in the order of writes, which may be inconsistent with reads. Should then some kind of pre-chaching and post-caching buffers be implemented?

Comment: @mbaitoff Yes, in that case your code can be easily parallelised. If your output has to be in a specific order then all you will need it to implement something similar to a reorder buffer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Re-order_buffer